# When to use Sequelize paranoid deletedAt

Tags: sequelize.js

Am trying to create a database and maintain a restful api service built upon sequelize.

I want a model, UserGameProfile, which can be deleted and restored according to user preference.

I want it to able to be deleted, and also open to other status like draft, cancelled, submitted, approved.

How useful is the Paranoid attribute in sequelize for this model?

Why should i consider using Paranoid attribute over something like a status column (int)?

Answer (score 0):

with paranoid: true you automatically get non-deleted records in all queries. If you wish to get all records including deleted ones you should indicate paranoid: false in options of a certain query.
This query gets you all non-deleted records with status=1

```
UserGameProfile.findAll({
where: {
status: 1
}})
```

This query gets you all records with status=1 including deleted ones

```
UserGameProfile.findAll({
where: {
status: 1
}, paranoid: false })
```